# Copy pasting multiple sheets into new workbook

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

The goal is to copy paste multiple existing sheets out of a workbook into a new workbook using xlwings. I have:

```
app = xw.App(visible=False)
book = xw.Book(path)

sheet_1 = book.sheets["Sheet1"]
sheet_2 = book.sheets["Sheet2"]

wb_res = xw.Book()
sheet_active = wb_res.sheets.active
sheet_1.api.Copy(Before=sheet_active)
```

This throws:

```
TypeError: Objects for SAFEARRAYS must be sequences (of sequences), or a buffer object.
```

Bonus question for the brave:
 - How can I replace all formulas on a sheet for its value?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use xlwings, or using some other library like `win32com` would also  suffice?

Comment: @MayankPorwal I can import win32com and win32com.client - not sure which versions I have tho... company updates python modules irregularly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `win32com`, you can try this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

path1 = 'workbook1.xlsx'
path2 = 'workbook2.xlsx'

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")

wb1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path1)
wb2 = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path2)

ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(1)
ws1.Copy(Before=wb2.Worksheets(1))

wb2.Close(SaveChanges=True)
xl.Quit()
```